# Unable to access jarfile using subprocess

Tags: java, python, jar, subprocess

I am trying to run a Java command in python like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['java -Xmx1024m -jar /maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar run /data/models/term_assignment_model -v /data/vocabulary/nyt_descriptors.rdf.gz -f skos'], cwd=r'/Users/username/Repositories/RAKE-tutorial/', shell=True)
```

Unfortunately it is throwing an `Unable to access jarfile /maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` error. I have checked the permissions and tried a number of other options including using the `os.system` command to run a shell script. The error still remains. There seem to be a lot of people who have encountered the same problem but none of their solutions seem to work for me. Any suggestions? Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to what you have entered your jar would be in the `/` directory  is that truely the case or is in at `./`?

Comment: ah, thank you...something so simple! a case of staring at the thing for too long!

Comment: @user2097159 any advice on the best way to print the results? I can assign a variable and print but the result is different from just running the java in command line. cheers

Comment: Look into subprocess.check_output.

Comment: Thanks @user2097159, I managed to get round it by putting the java in a bash script and calling that with `subprocess.check_output`.

Answer (score 0):

use fullpath to file

like

```
command = f"java -jar {os.path.dirname(__file__)}\\jar_name.jar"
process = subprocess.run(
    command,
    shell=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)
```

it help's me