# Getting java output in python

Tags: java, python, subprocess

Based on my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642609/unable-to-access-jarfile-using-subprocess), i am trying to run some java in python and get the results. So far my code looks like this:

```
import subprocess

a = subprocess.Popen(['java -Xmx1024m -jar ./maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar run /data/models/term_assignment_model -v /data/vocabulary/nyt_descriptors.rdf.gz -f skos'], cwd=r'/Users/samuelburke/Repositories/RAKE-tutorial/', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = a.communicate()

print out
```

The java on its own, when run in the command line returns a list of keywords from some text like so:

```
04 Jun 2015 12:49:10  INFO Vocabulary - --- Loading RDF model from the SKOS file...
04 Jun 2015 12:49:12  INFO Vocabulary - --- Building the Vocabulary index from the RDF model...
04 Jun 2015 12:49:12  INFO Vocabulary - --- Statistics about the vocabulary: 
04 Jun 2015 12:49:12  INFO Vocabulary -     498 terms in total
04 Jun 2015 12:49:12  INFO Vocabulary -     0 non-descriptive terms
04 Jun 2015 12:49:12  INFO Vocabulary -     0 terms have related terms
Keyword: Food 0.010580524344569287
Keyword: Theater 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Education and Schools 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Child Care 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Trees and Shrubs 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Sociology 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Wines 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Science and Technology 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Heart 0.0022471910112359544
Keyword: Evolution 0.0022471910112359544
```

However, running the above code returns this:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Name of model required argument.
    at com.entopix.maui.StandaloneMain.runMaui(StandaloneMain.java:40)
    at com.entopix.maui.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:109)
    ... 6 more
```

This is the first time I'm doing anything like this and I'm pretty new to programming so I think I might be approaching this all wrong. Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Try changing  `Popen(['java -Xmx1024m -jar...` to `Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024m', '-jar', ...`. Make each argument a separate element of the list.

Comment: @Kevin makes a good point, either use a list as `Popen` argument, where each command line argument is a separate string element, or use a whole string instead of that list, like `Popen('java -Xmx1024m -jar...`.

Comment: I gave it a try but the output is the same as running `java -help` in the command line.

Comment: this is currently what it looks like as per your suggestion: `Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024m', '-jar', './maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', 'run', '/data/models/term_assignment_model', '-v', '/data/vocabulary/nyt_descriptors.rdf.gz', '-f', 'skos']...) `, if that's what you meant. I tried a couple of variations but no luck.